# External Accessory Framework can launch terminated app?

Tags: bluetooth, frameworks, external, accessory

Anyone knows if external accessory can launch terminated apps in iOS?

The documentation, from Apple, says that "Declaring support for specific protocols lets the system know that your app can be launched when that accessory is connected".

So if my app register a protocol X, and I connect my iPhone to a bluetooth accessory that has that protocol (X), my app is launched, in background, even if is terminated (like CoreBluetooth)? And I can send commands to that accessory?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think it's clear from the [External Accessory Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/featuredarticles/ExternalAccessoryPT/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009502), which you quoted (copied below), that the app can be launched, meaning the app didn't need to be already running in the fore or background. However "launched" to me does not imply launched in the background, such as is done with the CoreBluetooth background modes, but rather, it means launched normally into the foreground.

> Apps that are able to communicate with an external accessory must declare the protocols they support in their Info.plist file. Declaring support for specific protocols lets the system know that your app can be launched when that accessory is connected. If no app supports the connected accessory, the system may choose to launch the App Store and point out apps that do.